# Suppose that r is a vector differentiable function of t, and w is a real function differentiable from t. Show that ⅆ/ⅆt [r(w(t))]=r^' (w(t)) w^' (t)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I do not know how to do demonstrations, I have really try, but I can not solve this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax formating (See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be an interval in $ \mathbb R$ and $r:I \to \mathbb R^n$ a differentiable function, then $r(t)=(r_1(t),...,r_n(t))$ for $t \in I.$ We have that each $r_j:I \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable on $I$. If $J$ is a further interval in $ \mathbb R$ and $w:J \to I$ is differentiable, then we have , by the usual chain rule, that

$$\frac{d}{dt}(r_j(w(t))=r_j'(w(t)) w'(t)$$

for $j=1,...,n$ and $t \in J.$

This gives the result.